# Group by matching data id and order by another data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Is it possible to group a number of divs by matching data-id and order it by another data attribute. Can this be done with underscorejs or plain javascript?

**Current layout of div**
and
**Desired output**

```html
    <div id="parentID">
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 71 Order 2</div>
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 71 Order 3</div>
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 71 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="62" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 62 Order 2</div>
      <div data-id="62" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 62 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 59 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 59 Order 3</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 59 Order 2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="parentID">
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 71 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 71 Order 2</div>
      <div data-id="71" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 71 Order 3</div>
      <div data-id="62" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 62 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="62" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 62 Order 2</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 59 Order 1</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 59 Order 2</div>
      <div data-id="59" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 59 Order 3</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your `div` on `id` and `orderby` attribute.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#parentID div").sort((a,b) => {
      return $(b).data('id') - $(a).data('id') || $(a).data('orderby') - $(b).data('orderby');
  }).appendTo('#parentID');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentID">
  <div data-id="71" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 71 Order 2</div>
  <div data-id="71" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 71 Order 3</div>
  <div data-id="71" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 71 Order 1</div>
  <div data-id="62" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 62 Order 2</div>
  <div data-id="62" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 62 Order 1</div>
  <div data-id="59" data-orderby="1" class="child">ID: 59 Order 1</div>
  <div data-id="59" data-orderby="3" class="child">ID: 59 Order 3</div>
  <div data-id="59" data-orderby="2" class="child">ID: 59 Order 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this script

```
$("#parentID div.child").sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data("id") - $(b).data("id");
}).appendTo("#parentID");
```

Comment: Is it possible to group the data ids and then sort by orderby values with this? This doesnt reorder the data-orderby values.

Comment: yes you can change this line by  return $(a).data("orderby") - $(b).data("orderby");

Comment: This would then only group by the orderby data? I was hoping to get the output layout of my desired output. The data-ids are together then ordered 1,2,3.